# Move directory and its contents to another directory

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems

I'm trying to familiarize myself with C++17's filesystem library and I'm trying to implement the function

```
bool MoveFolder(std::string_view oldRelativePath, std::string_view newRelativePath)
```

which will take the folder at `oldRelativePath` and move it under `newRelativePath`. I've been fiddling around for an hour but no luck. How can I implement this function with `std::filesystem`? On any error, I would like to return false.

Answer (score 1):

You use [std::filesystem::rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename), of course.

> Moves or renames the filesystem object identified by old_p to new_p as if by the POSIX [rename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html).

Comment: Does this take everything (including subfolders) in the folder and move it to the destination? I tried this and it just errd. That is why I decided to implement it myself.

Comment: @DogaOruc: Have you never renamed a folder before, like in the GUI for your desktop?

Comment: @DogaOruc yes, it should. Assuming you have the correct path and the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem with my earlier approach with `std::filesystem::rename`. Rename, as the name suggests, renames. It doesn't move. I was trying to use it like so:

```
fs::path p = fs::current_path() / "sandbox";
fs::create_directories(p / "from");
std::ofstream(p / "from/file1.txt").put('a');
fs::create_directory(p / "to");
fs::rename(p / "from", p / "to"); // NOT-OK
fs::remove_all(p);
```

This would lead to `from` being renamed to `to`, it wouldn't actually move `from` under `to`, which was what I wanted to do. Here's a simple way to achieve it:

```
fs::path p = fs::current_path() / "sandbox";
fs::create_directories(p / "from");
std::ofstream(p / "from/file1.txt").put('a');
fs::create_directory(p / "to");
fs::path ppp(p/"from");
fs::rename(p / "from", p / "to" / ppp.filename()); // OK
fs::remove_all(p);
```

And here is the function I've been desperately trying to implement...

```
bool MoveFolder(std::string_view oldRelativePath, std::string_view newRelativePath) {
   fs::path old(oldRelativePath);
   fs::path neww(newRelativePath);
   std::error_code err;
   fs::rename(old, old / neww.filename(), err);
   return !static_cast<bool>(err);
}
```